# How to have div fill width and height of browser window and not have the image be stretched

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have an image in a browser height and width filling div and want the image to scale to fit, it currently stretches. I want to use the image as you normally use a background image. I can't in this case because it switches using its HTML ID

my CSS

```
    .cover{
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:block; 
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

my HTML

```
<div class="cover" id="1">
    <img class="cover" src="Images/Articles/Index/MRD%2008-041.jpg">


   <a href="Articles/boy.html"> 
   <span class="title">The Next Generation of Film<br>is in Our Own Backyard</span></a>

   <span class="post"> North Toronto sees yet another high budget Disney movie Filmed on     it's grounds.</span>
 </div>
```

and a jsfiddle for good [measure](http://jsfiddle.net/W925K/2/#run). again, how do I make the Image fill the height and width of the browser window without stretching the image? Thanks

Comment: r u looking like this? http://jsfiddle.net/W925K/3/

Comment: `i cant in this case because it switches using its html ID` If the class stays the same, why not just use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display your image through the CSS using `background-image` and apply the extra property `background-size` to make it fill the container.

Here’s a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W925K/4/).

HTML

```
<div class="cover" id="1">
    <a href="Articles/boy.html"> 
       <span class="title">The Next Generation of Film<br>is in Our Own Backyard</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
// Required to allow the .cover container to fill the entire window. min-height could do the trick too depending on your wishes
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.cover {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    background: url('http://placehold.it/550x300') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: it worked, is there any way i can refrence the image in html though?

Comment: Why would you do that? You could do it but then you’ll need JavaScript to make the image fit and you’ll have some limitations in your layout then.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `background-image` instead of `<img>` tag.

`<img>` is not a good choice for dynamically sized images, CSS does it better.

### background-size

CSS3 supports two new values for `background-size`, `cover` and `contain`.

From [MDN background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size):

> cover
>
> This keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as small as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are greater than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area.
>
> contain
>
> This keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as large as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are less than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area.